# Store query results in file

Tags: store, elasticsearch

Is there anyway to store the Elasticsearch  output in file? 
For example, in .txt file?

Answer (score 0):

If you working on a .Net project, XML file will be a better choice.

Comment: no I just want to do some language  analysis of  the text file after storing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/scroll.html) along with [JAVA Api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/search.html) to fetch all the documents from ES. You can then  straightway write these JSON string  to txt file or you can parse them and store in csv or other format.